# Python Random Number Game defaults to wrong answer

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a Simple Python program that asks the user to guess a number between 1 and  ten and takes advantage of the randint function in python.
At first everything seemed great as it would for sure mark a wrong answer as wrong, but when I kept trying it to see the permutations it marked a right answer as wrong.

Here is the code:

```
import random

cont = True

while cont:
    var1 = random.randint(1, 10)
    #var1 = 6
    print("Pick a number between One and Ten")
    varans = input()
    #varans = 6
    if varans == var1:
        print("The right answer was...")
        print(var1)
        print("Your Answer was...")
        print(varans)
        print("You chose wisely. You win!")

    elif varans != var1:
        print("The right answer was...")
        print(var1)
        print("Your Answer was...")
        print(varans)
        print("Sorry, You lose!")

    print("Do you want to continue?")
    choice = input()
    choice = choice.lower()
    if choice != "y":
        cont = False
```

the commented parts were from when I was testing it to see if it was even evaluating anything. I hardcoded a Correct answer to see if that part would work. The odd thing is it did work but for some reason, I can't get it to work with the original code. I'm probably missing something simple. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You're comparing a string and an integer `"6" == 6`?. They'll never be equal. Use a cast `int(input())`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That did it! I knew it was something simple. I forgot about casting. I'm still very new to python so this helped a lot.

Comment: It's likely happened to everyone that's ever learned the language. Welcome aboard the Python Train.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input` will return a string. Therefore, it will never be equal to any `int`.

You can either convert your random integer to a string

```
var1 = str(random.randint(1, 10))
```

Or covert the user input from a string to an integer

```
varans = int(input())
```

And all should be well in the world.

Comment: Glad it helped, and welcome to SO. One important thing you'll learn quickly about SO is that, as a matter of keeping things quality here, contributors can get a bit picky about the questions that are asked. I encourage you to check out the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article to see what kind of qualities we look for in questions. Whether learning Python or how to use SO, we all start somewhere! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue with your code is that you are comparing an int to a string. To fix this you can do either `varans = int(input())` or `var1 = str(random.randint(1, 10))`. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. For some reason casting completely slipped my mind and I thought it would pull the input in as an int automatically. My bad. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @AndrewDavidson No problem, I am glad to help. Feel free to mark the one either of the answers as the solution. Therefore, if someone else with a similar problem stumbles upon this thread in the future, they can easily determine the solution that worked for you.